# eXist transform passing parameter to XSLT - must declare in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xquery, exist-db

Environment: eXist-db 4.2.1 , XQuery 3.1, XSLT 2.0

Using eXist's [transform:transform](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/xsl-transform) function, I want to pass the following parameters to an XSLT doc:

```
let $xsltransform := transform:transform(
                        $currentdoc, 
                        concat($globalvar:URIstyles,
                        "document_style.xsl"),
                        (<parameters>
                            <param name="paramPersonurl" 
                                  value="{$globalvar:URLperson}"/>
                            <param name="paramPlaceurl" 
                                  value="{$globalvar:URLplace}"/>
                            <param name="paramDocurl" 
                                  value="{$globalvar:URLdoc}"/>
                         </parameters>))
```

Do I have to 'declare' these parameters in the XSLT file before using them? Like so:

```
<!-- parameters coming from eXist -->
<xsl:param name="paramPersonurl"/>
<xsl:param name="paramPlaceurl"/>
<xsl:param name="paramDocurl"/>
```

Or can I just go straight to using them in XSLT like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$paramPersonurl"/>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you almost certainly have to declare them, but the way to find out for sure is to try it and see what happens. Thanks!

Comment: Tim C. You are correct, i.e. you do have to declare them. I think you should add it as an answer so you get the Kudos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "Yes". You do have to declare them, otherwise it wouldn't really be a valid XSLT document.

(In theory, even if eXist did automatically add the parameters, it would still be better to declare them as you would want your XSLT to be re-usable elsewhere should you ever change technologies in the future)